# Why file input change does not work repeatly?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following code:

```
   <input type="file" #fileInput ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event)" />
```

And handler:

```
   public onFileSelected(e: FileList): void {
        this.form.patchValue({ filename: e[0].name });
    }
```

Problem is when I try to select the same file, selected before, input does not chnaged and dont send event: `e: FileList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the input file value when pressing the input file button.

```
<input id="fileInput" onclick="fileClicked()" type="file">
<script>
function fileClicked(){
    document.getElementById("#fileInput").value = "";
}
</script>
```